# Rails Console not loading? y (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

I'm all of the sudden getting the follow error message when I try to load the rails console.  I just recently switched databases to postgres, which has given me a slew of problems (although I must admit I like it a lot better than mysql!), so I'm assuming this is related to that.  Any ideas?

```
y (Errno::ENOENT)/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': No such file or directory - /usr/local/lib/?
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/environment.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:23:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/benyorke/rubystore/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you delete something?

Comment: No I used homebrew to install it, then added pg to the gemfile and ran a bundle install command.  The problems I expirienced were with the autoload of postgres, which didnt require deleting anything

Comment: Did you add the postgres headers/binaries in your `PATH`?  What does `which postgres` say?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be a bug with Ruby 1.9.3-p327 that just got fixed by Ruby 1.9.3-p385. Does upgrading to 1.9.3-p385 fix it for you?

What seems peculiar in this error message, and is similar to issues I've been having, is the question mark at the end of the path: `No such file or directory - /usr/local/lib/?`. I've been getting similar strange error messages related to ruby's require and paths with question marks, at symbols, or other random characters at the end of paths after upgrading to 1.9.3-p327 from 1.9.3-p194 a few weeks ago. However, the issues have been extremely sporadic, and around the same time we experienced some hardware failures, so it's been tough to track down.

Today the issue started happening consistently in one specific context, so I was able to do some additional debugging. Updating to 1.9.3-p385 seems to have fixed it, but given the sporadic nature of the issues I've been experiencing, I'm not entirely 100% this is actually the fix. I'm also not entirely sure if this is the same issue you're having. The mysterious question mark in the path just makes it appear like it might be related. Here are a couple examples of the type of errors we were getting:

```
No such file or directory - /srv/shared/rails/internal/admin/vendor/bun@

No such file or directory - /srv/shared/rails/internal/admin/vendor?
```

If it's at all related to the same issues I've been experiencing, but the 1.9.3-p385 upgrade doesn't fix it, a few other notes or things to explore:

- I was able to reproduce this problem today on 1.9.3-p327 and 1.9.3-p374. However, the problem didn't seem present on 1.9.3-p194, 1.9.3-p286, and 1.9.3-p385.
- Are you using symlinks anywhere in in your gem load path? For example, we use Bundler to install gems into a local `vendor/bundle` path inside each application. But the `vendor/bundle` is actually a symlink to another location (this is related to a Capistrano deployment setup). I believe the symlink was possibly playing a role. In today's tests, if I wasn't using a symlink, the problem disappeared on all versions of ruby.
- Do you use [bundler-exec](https://github.com/gma/bundler-exec)? On another occasion where this problem was happening somewhat sporadically, bypassing the aliases bundler-exec also seemed to magically fix things, but today's problem wasn't even touching bundler-exec, so I'm not too sure.
- Most of the time our problem was very random (it would go away after a few attempts of running the same command), but on a few occasions, the problem would persist for an hour or more before disappearing.
- Some information about our systems:

  - 64bit RedHat Enterprise Linux 6
  - Bundler 1.2.3
  - Rubygems 1.2.5 (also happened under 1.2.4)
  - rbenv

But like I said, this issue also happened to coincide with some hardware disk failures and general server wonkiness on our end, so I haven't really been certain if this was a Ruby issue or what's been going on. But here's to hoping 1.9.3-p385 actually fixes it.

Comment: check out my post above if you continue to have the error.  Sorry it dosn't specify the issue, but it did work for me.  The big one was installing the postgres gem on my machine, even though my gemfile only is using the pg gem

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not updating this thread - I have actually been working on this in the background for a few weeks now.  I couldn't find ANY information on this online, so I'm going to post as detailed of a solution as I can.

---

## The Issues

The issues I was having was that I could not access rails console, and I had to manually start the postgres server every-time I restarted my machine.  My solutions to that, as I have worked with this for a few weeks were

**In regards to the console** I used herokus console.  By pushing my app to heroku (which is free) not only could I view it on the web (any machine) but on my machine I could run

```
$ heroku run console
```

and get access to a console.  Now this isn't a perfect solution in anyway as I can't manipulate data on my machine but it saved me many times

**In regards to the server** I ran

```
$ brew info postgres
```

which gave me the commands to manually restart the server

```
You should reload postgresql:
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

---

## The Solution

To be honest, I have run every command I can find dozens of times, and just today got it working.  I don't know if I was making typos, doing it in an ineffective order, mixing up pg/postgres/postgresql or what but what I did below worked

**When using this solution, it will erase all databases.  Migrations will be able to rebuild the structure, but any data will be lost**

### 1. Updated Homebrew

```
$ brew update
```

*If you don't have home-brew, check out this page for instructions to install (saved my neck with many things, including minimagick imagemagick and postgres!): [Link](https://brew.sh)*

### 2. Removed postgresql

```
$ brew rm postgresql --force
```

### 3. Installed postgreql

```
$ brew install postgresql
```

*This is the first step to reference postgres. When looking online, I ran across commands that used postgresql, postgres, and pg.  Postgresql refers to the actually PostgreSQL program.  postgres and pg are ruby gems, which we will get to later*

### 4. Ran suggested commands

After running "$ brew install postgres" there is a lot of information given to you.  Make sure to read through it, as it will suggest what commands to run.  Use these suggestions to find the commands I reference below.
**If you need to access this information later simply run**

```
$ brew info postgresql
```

To initialize the database

```
$ initdb file/path
```

Set up the autolauncher

```
$ cp file/path ~ LaunchAgents/file/path
```

Launch postgresql initially

```
$ launchctl load file/path
$ pg_ctl-D file/oath
```

### 5. Download Postgres.app

Although to my knowledge this seems redundant, this is what got it to work on my mac.  visit http://postgresapp.com to download

### 6. Install gems

There are two gems - postgres and pg.  I required pg in my gemfile and ran a bundle install command, however it still gave me issues until I installed postgres on my machine - even though it is not required in my gemfile, rails console wont seem to work without it atleast installed

In the gem file

```
gem 'pg'
```

Run a bundle install command in a terminal window

```
$ bundle install
```

Sudo install the postgres gem

```
$ sudo gem install postgres
```

---

At this point everything should be working. You should be able to restart the machine and not have any problems!